# R reading csv file with different seperators

Tags: r

I wanna read a csv file where the first line is written like this:

GeoFIPS,GeoName,Region,TableName,LineCode,IndustryClassification,Description,Unit,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019

The following lines are written like this (just one line of 500):

"01000","Alabama",5,SAGDP1,2,"...","Chain-type quantity indexes for real GDP","Quantity index",77.435,80.198,83.178,84.532,84.232,86.440,88.581,94.298,97.490,99.348,99.971,99.317,95.894,98.103,99.525,100.000,101.212,100.544,101.541,102.664,103.827,106.164,107.652

How can I read this file so that all the values are seperated correctly?

With the command: gdp_data <- read.csv("GDP.csv", sep = ",")   only the headers get seperated correctly the text of the further lines is all put in the first column.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that some of your columns are unnamed rateher than the "different separators".  (I don't think there are any different separators.)

Assuming you know in advance how many columns there are, then something like this should work.

```
readr::read_csv(
  "<your file name>",
  # Provide custom file names
  col_names=c("GeoFIPS","GeoName","Region","TableName", paste0("X", 5:7))
) %>% 
  # Remove first row of "column names"
filter(row_number() > 1)

# A tibble: 1 x 7
  GeoFIPS GeoName       Region TableName    X5 X6    X7                                         
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                      
1 00000   United States dummy  SAGDP1        1 ...   Real GDP (millions of chained 2012 dollars)
```

You could, of course, provide more meaningful names for the unnamed columns.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the whole line, as it is super long and therefore I made it look like some columns are missing. But this is actually not a problem, all columns are there.
The problem is that if I make the folowwing command:
gdp_data <- read.csv("GDP.csv", sep = ",")
only the header is seperated correctly but for the further rows the whole text is put in the same column.

Comment: Then please post a MWE which *does* illustrate your problem.  otherwise, we are working in the dark.  Also, norte that I am using a different function to read the data in: `read_csv` rather than `read.csv`.  Does that help?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with either `read_csv` or `read.csv`.  Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for advice on how to create a MWE.  The `reprex` package may also help.